# Destroying Windows in GTK#

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have a dialogue in GTK# that gets opened by a mouse click, and after clicking a button in it, the dialogue should be closed again. Do I have to call both methods Hide() and Destroy() on the window?

Here is my code to launch the dialogue:

```
protected virtual void ConfigureDialogue (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MyConfigWindow myConfWindow = new MyConfigWindow ();
    this.Sensitive = false;
    myConfWindow.Run ();
    this.Sensitive = true;
}
```

And here is the relevant part of the config window:

```
public partial class MyConfigWindow  : Gtk.Dialog
{

    public MyConfigWindow ()
    {
        this.Build();
    }

    protected virtual void onSave (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        this.Destroy ();
    }
}
```

When I only call `this.Destroy ()` the main window gets sensitive again (therefore `myConfWindow.Run ()` has ended), but the dialogue is still visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your missing the destroy call in the ConfigureDialog procedure ...

```
  this.Sensitive = false; 
  result = myConfWindow.run();
  if (result == gtk.RESPONSE_CLOSE:)
    myConfWindow.destroy();
  this.Sensitive = true;
```

Hope that helps.